# Why does `conda update qt` update Spyder the best?

Tags: python, qt, anaconda, spyder, updates

No matter if I tried `conda update spyder`, or `conda remove spyder` followed by `conda install spyder`, I could never get anaconda to update to Spyder version 4.1.5, with these commands claiming that version 4.0 is already the latest version.

Finally, when I tried the command `conda update qt` it prompted the additional installation of Spyder 4.1.5 automatically. Why did this command do it, and the normal ones failed? What exactly is `qt`? Don't just say binding. what does it stand for and everything

Comment: Since you have tagged your question `qt`, you might as well read the [tag description](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/qt/info).

Answer (score 1):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) [Qt](https://www.qt.io/) is a library to create graphical applications in all operating systems (Windows, Linux and macOS). Spyder is based on that library.

I'm not sure why running `conda update qt` updates Spyder, but it's certainly one of Spyder dependencies.

What we usually recommend to update Spyder is to run the following commands:

`conda update anaconda`

`conda update spyder`

Comment: On windows 10 `update qt` was the only command that upgraded spyder